# How to save downloaded file from server in java

Tags: java, download-manager

i have a java class to download file from server, this file start downloading and also completed the download , but it not give the path where it is saved in the local system , or i think it not save the file , please guide me how i save it in the download folder of window or in any other folder.

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;



    class Download extends Observable implements Runnable {


    private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    public static final String STATUSES[] = {"Downloading",
        "Paused", "Complete", "Cancelled", "Error"};

    public static final int DOWNLOADING = 0;
    public static final int PAUSED = 1;
    public static final int COMPLETE = 2;
    public static final int CANCELLED = 3;
    public static final int ERROR = 4;

    private final URL url; // download URL
    private int size; // size of download in bytes
    private int downloaded; // number of bytes downloaded
    private int status; // current status of download

    public Download(URL url) {
        this.url = url;
        size = -1;
        downloaded = 0;
        status = DOWNLOADING;

        // Begin the download.
        download();
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url.toString();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public float getProgress() {
        return ((float) downloaded / size) * 100;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void pause() {
        status = PAUSED;
        stateChanged();
    }

    public void resume() {
        status = DOWNLOADING;
        stateChanged();
        download();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        status = CANCELLED;
        stateChanged();
    }

    private void error() {
        status = ERROR;
        stateChanged();
    }

    private void download() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    private String getFileName(URL url) {
        String fileName = url.getFile();
        return fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    }

    public void run() {
        RandomAccessFile file = null;
        InputStream stream = null;

        try {
            // Open connection to URL.
            HttpURLConnection connection
                    = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Specify what portion of file to download.
            connection.setRequestProperty("Range",
                    "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");

            // Connect to server.
            connection.connect();

            // Make sure response code is in the 200 range.
            if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2) {
                error();
            }

            // Check for valid content length.
            int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
            if (contentLength < 1) {
                error();
            }

            /* Set the size for this download if it
     hasn't been already set. */
            if (size == -1) {
                size = contentLength;
                stateChanged();
            }

            // Open file and seek to the end of it.
            file = new RandomAccessFile(getFileName(url), "rw");
            file.seek(downloaded);

            stream = connection.getInputStream();
            while (status == DOWNLOADING) {
                /* Size buffer according to how much of the
       file is left to download. */
                byte buffer[];
                if (size - downloaded > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                    buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                } else {
                    buffer = new byte[size - downloaded];
                }

                // Read from server into buffer.
                int read = stream.read(buffer);
                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }

                // Write buffer to file.
                file.write(buffer, 0, read);
                downloaded += read;
                stateChanged();
            }


            /* Change status to complete if this point was
     reached because downloading has finished. */
            if (status == DOWNLOADING) {
                status = COMPLETE;
                stateChanged();
                System.err.println("cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error();
        } finally {
            // Close file.
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    file.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            // Close connection to server.
            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

// Notify observers that this download's status has changed.
    private void stateChanged() {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the **RandomAccessFile()**, the first parameter is the file name and location. Try print the absolutePath() and see where this file resident.

Comment: can you please tell me where i have to put this code?

Comment: Try create new RandomAccessFile("c:\\temp\\myfile.txt", "RW") then the content downloaded should be written to this file, based on your original code. I can see that you tried to match the filename from the URL. So if that is the case, the file should be saved in the location where you start your application. Again, call file.getAbsolutePath() should reveal the file location.